# how to remove the css given and get only the data from database using php

Tags: php, css

am having data in database as

```
            <p style="display: inline;">2012-2013</p>
```

but what i have to get is 2012-2013 only. is it possible. If so can someone help me please thanks.

am getting data using

```
      <?php echo $this->data1[0]->content;?>
```

How to use the iterative operator to get the value into textbox in html and PHP
Hi am having as follows:

```
             <div class="text_right"><input type="text" name="name" id="name" autofocus  minlength="4" size="30" value="<?php echo empty($this->session->store['loginData']['username']) ? '' : $this->session->store['loginData']['username']; ?>" readonly /><br  /><br  />
    </div>
```

But what I need is I have to fill the textbox with a session value `$this->session->store['respondent_info']['name']`, if that session value is empty then I have to fill that textbox with `$this->session->store['loginData']['username'];`  is it possible if so can someone help me please.

Comment: Do you want to remove only the `style` attribute, or the `<p>` element entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `strip_tags` for this purpose

```
<?php echo strip_tags($this->data1[0]->content;)?>
```

if you want to allow some tags:

```
<?php 
    $content = $this->data1[0]->content;
    strip_tags($content , '<p><h1>'); /* this would allow 'p' and 'h1' inside the text*/
?>
```

Refer more here : **http://ch2.php.net/strip_tags** , also, if you are considering to make data secure/clean before inserting and while outputting, looks into  [**htmlspecialchars**](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)  too!!

**EDIT**

IF you want to set values after checking whether session_exists or not:

```
if(session_id() == '')
 {
      // session has NOT been started
      $value =  "some_default_value"
 }
 else
 {
      // session has been started
      $value = $this->session->store['loginData']['username'];
 }
```

IF you want to check if particular value in session exists or not:

use `isset` and `empty` tags

```
if(isset($_SESSION['your_id_to_check']) && !empty($_SESSION['your_id_to_check'])) {
  // id exists and is not null

}
else
{
   //may be id does not exists or may be it exists but its null
}
```

Comment: i have doubt can i ask?

Comment: @user3243029 : sure...what is it??

Comment: am having an iterative operator in that i need to use the condition that if session value is empty it has to show another data if not it has to show this session data

Comment: @user3243029 : so basically if `session` is set, you want to show another data...right??? or you are targeting a particular `id` in  `session`???

Comment: hi i have edited the question. Can you check it and say

Comment: @user3243029 : edited answer too...covered both scenario, all yours now :)

Comment: how can we show it in this <div class="text_right"><input type="text" name="name" id="name" autofocus  minlength="4" size="30" value="<?php echo empty($this->session->store['loginData']['username']) ? '' : $this->session->store['loginData']['username']; ?>"  /><br  /><br  />
    </div> using this operator

Comment: @user3243029 : for value, use it this way `value=<?php echo $value ?>` and store `$value`'s value using the condition above....still confusing!? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php echo strip_tags($this->data1[0]->content); ?>
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is strip HTML tags. Just use `strip_tags()` function in PHP.

More on strip_tags(): https://www.php.net/strip_tags